# How to display a Calendar with Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I've been looking for a while how to try to make a calendar composable, since from what I've seen they haven't currently developed a calendar component like there used to be with XML.

[image]

In principle, the idea is to have a calendar that shows a month with all its days, and when clicking on an arrow, it shows the rest of the months, and with a list of days that comes from the service, the corresponding days are marked in one colour, and the current day in another colour.

Comment: "they haven't currently developed a calendar component" -- who is "they"? https://github.com/boguszpawlowski/ComposeCalendar comes up with a search for `"jetpack compose" calendar` on a major search engine. "like there used to be with XML" -- you could [use that from Compose UI as well](https://sgkantamani.medium.com/how-to-show-date-picker-in-jetpack-compose-8bc77a3ce408).